# Computing Cosets and the Kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we let $h:\Bbb{Z}_3\to \Bbb{Z}_3 \times\Bbb{Z}_6$ where $h(a) = (a,2a)$

What is the kernel and how can cosets be defined on this function? Any assistance or solutions are welcome.

Comment: It has trivial kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** An element '$a$'belongs to the Kernel of a mapping if it is mapped to identity.

Note, $(0,0)$ is the identity of $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_6$

$h(a)=(a\pmod3,2a\pmod6)=(0,0)$.

Can you find all such $a$'s?